# How To Fix 'Android - SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length' Error Without Changing Keyboard?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I keep getting the 'SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length' error while making an app with EditText. I have used an onKey listener and have made numerous changes but nothing fixes it.
Here is the code:
`

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final EditText ko = findViewById(R.id.one);
    final EditText ma = findViewById(R.id.two);
    final EditText ko1 = findViewById(R.id.three);
    final EditText xa = findViewById(R.id.four);
    final TextView te = findViewById(R.id.ko);
    ko.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if(i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                ko.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                ma.requestFocus();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    ma.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent k) {
            if(i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                ma.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                ko1.requestFocus();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    ko1.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent t) {
            if(i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                ko1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                xa.requestFocus();
                return true;
            }
            return false;}
    });


}
public void onClick(View v){
    EditText ko = findViewById(R.id.one);
    EditText ma = findViewById(R.id.two);
    EditText ko1 = findViewById(R.id.three);
    EditText xa = findViewById(R.id.four);
    String t = ko.getText().toString();
    String u = ma.getText().toString();
    String x = ko1.getText().toString();
    String w = xa.getText().toString();
    String total = t +" "+ u +" "+x + " " +w;
    Toast.makeText(this, total,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

}
`